# Force CKEditor to load an HTML file from disk

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to use CKEditor to edit fairly long HTML files. I need to edit the underlying HTML a bit but the search and replace plug-in doesn't work on the underlying code. And I want to automate via a keyboard shortcut or macro the things I do over and over.

For example, I repeatedly need to change the name of a specific div class--e.g., from "todo" to "done".

....div class="todo".....   ===>  ....div class="done"....

I am doing this now by using Autohotkey macros to automate mouse movements and mouse clicks, and toggling into and out of Source mode, but this is very clunky and unreliable. Since I do this daily for maybe 30 sections of a displayed file, I want it to be speedy and robust. I'd like to use Python or Autohotkey to work on the underlying file. So my question is: when the underlying file is changed, how can I automate getting CKEditor to update--i.e., to reload the file from disk?

The goal is to have a single keystroke that will call Python or AHK, use them to make the change in the file, then force CKE to update the display ("done" reveals itself by changing the background color of that section).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can't read file directly from disc. (Except, selecting manually, e.g. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)
So it's required to use server-side language, and get file content on page load or with AJAX request.

For example with ajax jquery

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/path/to/your/file.html",
        async: false,
        success: function (result){
            CKEDITOR.instances["YOUR_INSTANCE"].setData(result)
        }
    });
```

However, for task like changing class and other html related. it's possible to use javascript / jquery to manipulate with CKEDITOR content.

e.g.

HTML

```
<textarea id="ckeditor"><div class="todo">lol</div></textarea>
```

JS

```
CKEDITOR.replace("ckeditor", { allowedContent: true, });

CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {      
    $(CKEDITOR.instances["ckeditor"].window.$.document).find('.todo').removeClass( "todo" ).addClass( "done" ); 
})
```

**UPDATE:**
You need to replace `url: "/path/to/your/file.html",` with path of file you want to open. (Please, also check if i was correct assuming your CKEditor instance is named 'editor1') And put this code after you load jquery.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(  
    $.ajax({
        url: "/path/to/your/file.html",
        async: false,
        success: function (result){
            CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].setData(result);
        }
    }));
</script>
```

Comment: This looks helpful. It's always the same file, in the same location, that I'm dealing with. So if I could call it when index.html loads or re-loads, that would do it. I will experiment.

Comment: No luck so far in loading the file. Probably because I'm unsure where to load it. What I've tried is putting your jquery code inside <script src="...> . . .</script> tags in index.htm . Is that the right way? I also have, above your code: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   and I put in the correct path to the desired file, and the name ('editor1') of the instance.

Comment: Looking again at the text of your message, I do need only to "get file content on page load"--if that helps.

Comment: @HarryBinswanger I updated my answer with possible realization. I hope in will work for you. If not, please, provide source of index.html ( So i could see there is problem )

Comment: Thanks so much for the update. Yes, I was making those substitutions, and yes editor1 is my editor instance, but I'm just too ignorant about js and jquery to get this to work, so I'm going to hire a Filipino programmer do it.